# Access control which fired the SelectionChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf

If I define a Combobox within a DataGridTemplateColumn as below then there will be multiple Comboboxes for each new row added

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DataGridTempCol" Header="Items">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="combo" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key"   ItemsSource="{Binding comboBoxSelections, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" SelectionChanged="combo_SelectionChanged" >
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I now want to add SelectionChanged event for every Combox. I've tried the following

```
private void combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Every SelectedItem is one data object in Dictionary collection.
    KeyValuePair<string, string> selob =
        (KeyValuePair<string, string>)combo.SelectedItem;
    string selKey = selob.Key;
    string selvalue = selob.Value; 
}
```

but `combo` is not recognised as it isn't a single instance of a ComboBox. How do I refer to the ComboBox that generated the event and access the SelectedItem?

Comment: What is value of `e.OriginalSource` in your event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following? My first guess is that this should either give you the ComboBox or the entire DataGrid.

```
e.OriginalSource
```